# Show SSAS dimension attribute in Excel pivot table "More Fields"

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have an existing dimension in the SSAS cube and when I connect to the cube by Pivot table in Excel, I see that dimension, and I see hierarchy underneath , and underneath of that I see ...MoreFields, and some attributes of the dimension are shown here, but I cannot figure it out, what property to set in SSAS cube project to show/hide this fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to dimension tab, right click on your attribute. Set the attribute hierarchy visible to false. This will stop your attribute from being visible.